# Phonegap error - Unable to import Certificate

Tags: phonegap-build

Phonegap build for ios- 
Error - Unable to import Certificate - You can fix this here.

I have try more than two days but same issue appear again .

Answer (score 1):

The sequence in which you generate the certificate and the subsequent p12 file is very important. Also, the I found, that validating the p12 file prior to uploading to the PhoneGap build site will save you lots of time.

I found the the instruction for the above at: [Error - Unable to import certificate](http://www.yoofoo.com/blog/post/2016/01/11/phonegap-build-unable-to-import-certificate.aspx). Hope this helps.